# Code to Generate Sequential Number with a Prefix

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small userform with textboxes and comboboxes in it. There is a summary table in worksheet. What i want is, when the userform is initialised, the code should go through the table column (voucher # i.e. 2) and generate the next number in the textbox2.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim NextNum As Long, prefix As String
Dim i As Long

   prefix = "BPV/"
NextNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(2))

i = NextNum + 1

Me.TextBox2.Enabled = False
Me.TextBox2.Value = prefix & i

End Sub
```

When the userform runs, it doesnt calculate the next number in sequence. Kindly review and help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the initialize method is running?  The code you show is not valid because of the extra comma at the end of the first Dim statement.

Comment: Is the issue determining the max number?

Comment: yes it is. it only creates the number 1 after that it still showing the same number...

Comment: I'm not an expert, but if you place your code under `Private Sub UserForm_Click()` it works ok (when clicked). Don't know why is not working under Inicialize.

Comment: Actually i want to run the code when the userform initializes...

Comment: Replace `.Max(Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(2)` with `.Max(Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2))`

Comment: Still not generating the next sequence number i.e.2

Comment: What do you mean by "sequence"? Your code will check the maximun value of column2, and then will print that (+1) in the textbox. There is no loop, nor many textboxes, only TextBox2.

Comment: The sequence will be maintained by me. i..e first number is BPV/1 then the next number should be BPV/2 and so on......

Comment: Can't get you. If column B is filled with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, the TextBox2 in the form is disabled and shows "BVP/5", just as the code says. Don't know what do you mean by "next number" Are there more textboxes?

Comment: You are not understanding my point. on first user form generated a code BPV-1 and placed it in the table. When i try to make another entry to the table, the textbox should show the value BPV-2 but it shows BPV-1... The table column2 will be filled with BPV-1, BPV-2,.....

Comment: 1) Have you checked that numbers are placed in the table? 2) `UserForm_Initialize()` is, as its name suggest, for setting parameters before the form is displayed. Maybe you want to use `Activate` instead of `Initialize`.

Comment: When the first entry is placed in the table, the voucher # i.e. BPV-1 will automatically be placed in the table. When i try to put the next entry, the code should read through the column, determine the last value and then generate the next number i.e. BPV-2. i want it when the userform initialises.

Comment: "When I try to put the next entry...": how? The form is already Initialated, that's why you're not getting what you want. Unless you close your workbook and open it again.

Comment: its a userform initialization code not workbook. It should work when i close the userform and then reopen it.

Comment: Initialize: [This event fires only when an application first creates an instance of a form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/138819)

Comment: Would like to know if you were able to perform the task...

Comment: Well still not able to get rid of that problem...

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to generate a sequential number by row would be using the Excel function `=row()` and then format the number with the following `NumberFormat`:

```
"BP\//"000000
```

`Selection.Numberformat = """BP\//""000000"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One issue you might be having is that the BPV is preventing Excel from determining the max. Try something like the below for getting the current max.

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range

    Dim fr As Integer
    Dim lr As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim curr As Integer
    Dim max As Integer

    Set rng = Range("A:A")

    fr = Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(2).Find(What:="*", after:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
    lr = Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(2).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row


    For i = fr To lr
        If Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
            curr = Mid(Cells(i, 2), 4)
            If curr > max Then max = curr
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox (max)

End Sub
```

Comment: No it doesn't, I'm not writing you're entire code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know how you're doing this. But suppose that there is a button (Button1) in the worksheet that is calling the UserForm. The following code is doing something similar to what you want to achieve (I guess...).

In the module:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

In the Userform:

```
Dim NextNum As Long, prefix As String
Dim i As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    prefix = "BPV/"
    NextNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2))
    i = NextNum + 1

    Me.TextBox2.Enabled = False
    Me.TextBox2.Value = prefix & i
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = i
End Sub
```